# Make a Texture Clickable

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d-modelling

I've added multiple textures on 3D Model, I just want to get notified when any Texture is tapped or clicked with it's texture id, in my activity class.
Any help or suggestion are welcomed...

```
public static int loadTexture(final InputStream is) {
            Log.v("GLUtil", "Loading texture '" + is + "' from stream...");

            final int[] textureHandle = new int[1];

            GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandle, 0);
            GLUtil.checkGlError("glGenTextures");

            if (textureHandle[0] != 0) {
                Log.i("GLUtil", "Handler: " + textureHandle[0]);

                final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inScaled = false;

                // Read in the resource
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options);
                if (bitmap == null) {
                    throw new RuntimeException("couldnt load bitmap");
                }

                // Bind to the texture in OpenGL
                GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle[0]);
                GLUtil.checkGlError("glBindTexture");

                // Set filtering
                GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
                GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                        GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);

                // Load the bitmap into the bound texture.
                GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
                GLUtil.checkGlError("texImage2D");
                // Recycle the bitmap, since its data has been loaded into OpenGL.
                bitmap.recycle();

            }

            if (textureHandle[0] == 0) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error loading texture.");
            }

            return textureHandle[0];
        }
```

Comment: IMHO, you cannot detect a click on a texture. Each texture is bound to certain faces of your 3D model. What you want is to detect when a user clicks on one of the polygons the texture is bound to.

Comment: Thanks @ProXicT for your comment. Any link to something like this ?

Comment: Collision detection is quite a hard topic, you can start here:
http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/131598/advanced_collision_detection_.php?page=1

Comment: You need to figure out what textures are bound to which polygons. You basicly know the information when you're applying the textures to the polygons. Then it's just a matter of testing the collision of the polygons with a ray casted from your position to your 3D cursor position (take a look at unprojecting cursor from 2D to 3D).

Comment: @ProXicT Thanks for your help. One more thing,
There is an [App][1] on Playstore which works same like I need. In that app, you can rotate and select any part of brain. Any Idea about that?


  [1]: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.brainvoyager.android.BrainTutor

Comment: I've never done this before but maybe it's possible to apply come colour map on the 3D model which would be stores in some separate buffer and you would color pick the parts. You can then even multiply the colors to blend them together and change certain color upon the click.

For the rotation part, take a look at euler rotations, it's pretty easy math... If you'd like to go more hardcore, you can use quaternions and matrices to rotate your object.

Comment: Thanks @ProXicT. I've already achieved the rotation part. Just wanted to display a Toast like thing on tap of certain points. Lets see..
Thanks for your help so far.
PS: found another app that best describes my requirements
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.medical.EssentialSkeleton

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111527/discussion-between-proxict-and-waqar-khan).

Comment: Unfortunately chat.* is blocked by the our proxy server :(

Comment: I would definitelly go with the coloured model to distinguish between all parts of the model. 
As I said, I've never done such thing before but I'm sure there're some techniques described online.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try using different colors for each part.
Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome, good luck! ;-)